# Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): message: Unclosed quotation mark after the character string

Tags: php, sql-server, ubuntu

How do I sanitize the data so it won't cause any errors? I'm running ubuntu, php 5.3 and connecting to mssql.

This is my code:

```
            $body = $this->get_part($imap, $b, "TEXT/HTML");
            if($body == "")
            {
                $body = $this->get_part($imap, $b, "TEXT/PLAIN");
            }
            $header = imap_headerinfo($imap, $b);
            $subject = $header->subject;
            $fromaddress = $header->fromaddress;
            $body = str_replace("'", "''", $body);
            //$body = str_replace("\"", "\"\"", $body);
            /////////////////////////////
            $data = array('content'=>$body);
            $query = $PDO->prepare('insert into [tbl_test] (content) values (:content)');
            $query->execute($data);
            break;
```

Comment: your str_replace is unnecessary. pdo and prepared statements take care of any escaping you need to do.

Comment: Removed but still getting the same error.